# How can I find the area above the curve

Tags: c++, matlab, curve, numerical-integration

I have a question about finding the area of rectangle `S2` (above the curve). I want to find `S1/S2` like `(S - S2)/(S2)`, where `S = S1 + S2`.

I have 2 `vectors` of `double` (x;y) and I can find `S1 + S2`:

`S = (x.back() - x[0])*(y.back() - y[0])`)

Then I want to use numerical integration to find the whole area under the cruve `S2`, and then deduct `z` from `S2`:

`z = (x.back() - x[0])*(y[0] - 0)` , `S2 = S2 - z`

My question is: how to use numerical integration if I have no function, but have (x;y). For example, in matlab it looks like this with `feval`:

```
% Total area under the curve
ft = fittype('smoothingspline');
cf = fit(x,y,ft);
F = @(x) feval(cf,x);
S2 = quad(F,x(1),x(end));
```

In C++ I have:

```
#include "Functions.h"
std::vector<double>AreaRatio(std::vector<double>&x, std::vector<double>&y) {

double S(0.0), z(0.0), S2(0.), R(0.0);

S = (x.back() - x[0])*(y.back() - y[0]);
z = (x.back()*x[0])*(y[0]-0);
S2 = /.../ 
// Numerical methods (any library) to find the area under the curve, 
// but I don't know how to transfer function into function of Numerical integration, 
// because I have only coordinates. 
R = (S - S2) / S2;
return R;
}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Area of rectangle is its height multiplied with its width.

Comment: @ÖöTiib yes, I know, but I'am about how to find area above the curve using numerical integration without function, because I have only coordinates x and y.

Comment: You have your code in MATLAB, but the title asks about C++. Please also give the C++ code and explain why you currently use two languages, as this is very confusing

Comment: Your vectors contain coordinates of points (that define little rectangles) so sum areas of these rectangles to get the area.

Comment: @Adriaan I'm sorry to make you confused. Matlab's code here is like example what I want (about smt like feval, because to use numerical intergation I need the function

Comment: c++ by itself doesnt know about numerical integration. You either have to write your own integrator or pick a library. In any case your question is either too broad or should be reworded and moved to https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think what you're looking for; since you don't have the equation but do have the points; is an approximation (you're never going to do better); and the easiest to do is one where you sum the areas of all the known trapeziums (which is the basis for integration)

Comment: Simpsons rule is an exact integration technique for a spline up to and including cubic.

Comment: 1.  Are the 'x' values evenly spaced?  2.  Look up the "trapezium rule", and just add up the areas.

Comment: In matlab you should probably use `trapz` instead. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html
In C++ grab a library that has this, or write your own, it is simple enough and shown in the answer below.

Comment: Your problem seems twofold; you appear to not know C++ and you appear to not know mathematics (ie, how to integrate).  Is this accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but I think you need to go one step further back to first principles of integration...what it looks like your trying to do is find the area under the graph... to do that you need to treat it as slices [integration is this concept taken to the point where the delta approaches 0]

So calculate the area as little rectangles or evern better rectangles with triangles on top between each data point...

i.e.

```
    for(loop over data)
    {
        area += (data[1] + data[0]) * time/distance between data[1] and data[0]
    }
```

Once you have that subtract it from y_end * (x_end - x1)

You'd use numerical integration to give you the values of data - but buy the looks of it your either measuring them or doing something else to generate them.